# How to space buttons

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I am constructing a RelativeLayout programmatically, and it has 3 buttons - one in the center of the screen, and one above it and another below it.

How do I pad/space them to increase the empty space between the buttons?  They are placed almost immediately next to each other with my current code, which may lead to inadvertent mis-presses.

```
private RelativeLayout myLayout;

private void addButtons() {
  // Construct the 2 player game button.
  Button start2pGameButton = new Button(this);
  start2pGameButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){
      // Process the button tap and start a 2 player game.
      startFrozenBubble(2);
    }
  });
  start2pGameButton.setText("Player vs. CPU");
  start2pGameButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, 8);
  start2pGameButton.setWidth((int) (start2pGameButton.getTextSize() * 10));
  start2pGameButton.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
  start2pGameButton.setFadingEdgeLength(5);
  start2pGameButton.setShadowLayer(5, 5, 5, R.color.black);
  start2pGameButton.setId(BTN2_ID);
  LayoutParams myParams1 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  myParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
  myParams1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
  // Add view to layout.
  myLayout.addView(start2pGameButton, myParams1);
  // Construct the 1 player game button.
  Button start1pGameButton = new Button(this);
  start1pGameButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){
      // Process the button tap and start/resume a 1 player game.
      startFrozenBubble(1);
    }
  });
  start1pGameButton.setText("Puzzle");
  start1pGameButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, 8);
  start1pGameButton.setWidth((int) (start1pGameButton.getTextSize() * 10));
  start1pGameButton.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
  start1pGameButton.setFadingEdgeLength(5);
  start1pGameButton.setShadowLayer(5, 5, 5, R.color.black);
  start1pGameButton.setId(BTN1_ID);
  LayoutParams myParams2 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  myParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
  myParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, start2pGameButton.getId());
  // Add view to layout.
  myLayout.addView(start1pGameButton, myParams2);
  // Construct the options button.
  Button optionsButton = new Button(this);
  optionsButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){
      // Process the button tap and start the preferences activity.
      startPreferencesScreen();
    }
  });
  optionsButton.setText("Options");
  optionsButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, 8);
  optionsButton.setWidth((int) (optionsButton.getTextSize() * 10));
  optionsButton.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
  optionsButton.setFadingEdgeLength(5);
  optionsButton.setShadowLayer(5, 5, 5, R.color.black);
  optionsButton.setId(BTN3_ID);
  LayoutParams myParams3 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  myParams3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
  myParams3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, start2pGameButton.getId());
  // Add view to layout.
  myLayout.addView(optionsButton, myParams3);
}
```

Comment: set a margin for each button

Comment: Layout weights are one way to systematically space them in a layout based on unknown sizes of different screens.  And combining them with margins as suggested.  Typically one of those people that like to do their UI stuff as much as possible in XML.

Comment: Ya, xml makes this super simple. It's just a matter of android:layout_marginBottom="X". I'm not sure why there isn't a .setMargin method for buttons when writing in java, at least I didn't see one. There is a .setPadding method that you could try, but that probably wouldn't put space in between the buttons, just and more space inside the button.

Comment: I added the following two lines to each set of parameters prior to each addView():
    myParams1.topMargin = 15;

    myParams1.bottomMargin = 15;

Answer (score 1):

Hoping this will work for you

```
Button btn1 = new Button(this);
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // width, height
params.setMargins(top, left, bottom, right); // dp values in integers
relativeLayout.addView(btn1, params);
```

Comment: If it does not work, try RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Answer (score 0):

The most recommendable way to do it is using XML files to inflate your view properly layout and using margins, since you are doing this programatically, what you have to do is using the following code:

```
    //For the button on top
    MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams)yourButton.getLayoutParams();
    mlp.bottomMargin = xxValue;
    btn.setLayoutParams(mlp);

   //And the same for the one on the bottom but using mlp.topMargin
```

Hope this helps, regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setMargins` function to set margins of a View:

```
myParams1.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
```